# Fix eslint no-use-before-define automatically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint, utilities

The fix option for eslint is great:

```
eslint . --ext .js --fix
```

I run into lots of `no-use-before-define` issues when I fixup old code repositories.  I don't want to re-invent the wheel, is there any way to do what boils down to a sorting task?  I have hundreds of these files to do.  I searched about, but could not find any way to fix this issue without disabling the rule.

Comment: I'll rephrase it.  Eslint certainly counts as 'software tools commonly used by programmers', which is on topic though 'recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic' is off topic.  I did do research and hesitated before asking, but given the benefit to the community of a way to do this I decided it was on topic enough to ask the question.